# Oracle SQL: Replace NULLs in Col4 with Col 4's value from other row if values are the same in Col1, Col2, and Col3 for both rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Here is my sample data:

| SURGERY_DATE | ROOM_NM | SERVICE_NM | SURGEON_NM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-07 0:00:00 | ROOM 1 | Orthopedics | Johnson, B |
| 2022-08-11 0:00:00 | ROOM 4 | Cardiology | Glen, D |
| 2022-08-09 0:00:00 | ROOM 3 | Gynecology | Martin, R |
| 2022-08-11 0:00:00 | ROOM 2 | Cardiology | Glen, D |
| 2022-08-07 0:00:00 | ROOM 2 | Vascular | Joseph, L |
| 2022-08-07 0:00:00 | ROOM 1 | Anesthesiology | (null) |
| 2022-08-11 0:00:00 | ROOM 4 | Cardiology | (null) |
| 2022-08-07 0:00:00 | ROOM 1 | Orthopedics | (null) |
| 2022-08-07 0:00:00 | ROOM 2 | Head and Neck | (null) |
| 2022-08-09 0:00:00 | ROOM 3 | Gynecology | (null) |
| 2022-08-08 0:00:00 | ROOM 1 | Anesthesiology | (null) |

My expected output:

| SURGERY_DATE | ROOM_NM | SERVICE_NM | SURGEON_NM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-07 0:00:00 | ROOM 1 | Orthopedics | Johnson, B |
| 2022-08-11 0:00:00 | ROOM 4 | Cardiology | Glen, D |
| 2022-08-09 0:00:00 | ROOM 3 | Gynecology | Martin, R |
| 2022-08-11 0:00:00 | ROOM 2 | Cardiology | Glen, D |
| 2022-08-07 0:00:00 | ROOM 2 | Vascular | Joseph, L |
| 2022-08-07 0:00:00 | ROOM 1 | Anesthesiology | (null) |
| 2022-08-11 0:00:00 | ROOM 4 | Cardiology | Glen, D |
| 2022-08-07 0:00:00 | ROOM 1 | Orthopedics | Johnson, B |
| 2022-08-07 0:00:00 | ROOM 2 | Head and Neck | (null) |
| 2022-08-09 0:00:00 | ROOM 3 | Gynecology | Martin, R |
| 2022-08-08 0:00:00 | ROOM 1 | Anesthesiology | (null) |

For Oracle SQL Developer, I was wondering if there was a way to replace values of (null) in SURGEON_NM with the value of SURGEON_NM from row(s) where there are identical values in SURGERY_DATE, ROOM_NM, and SERVICE_NM.

I.e. In the first table above, Rows 1 and 8 have the same values in columns SURGERY_DATE, ROOM_NM, and SERVICE_NM. Row 8 has a (null) for SURGEON_NM, while Row 1 has a value of "Johnson, B". Is there a way where Row 8's (null) be replaced with "Johnson, B"?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: For reproducibility, can you offer the sample data in `insert` form? You'll also need to show the table definition.

Comment: Use a self-join or sub-query and coalesce.

Answer (score 1):

Use `COALESCE` and the `MAX` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT surgery_date,
       room_nm,
       service_nm,
       COALESCE(
         surgeon_nm,
         MAX(surgeon_nm) OVER (PARTITION BY surgery_date, room_nm, service_nm)
       ) AS surgeon_nm
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY
       surgery_date,
       room_nm,
       service_nm,
       surgeon_nm;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (SURGERY_DATE, ROOM_NM, SERVICE_NM, SURGEON_NM) AS
SELECT DATE '2022-08-07', 'ROOM 1', 'Orthopedics', 'Johnson, B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-08-11', 'ROOM 4', 'Cardiology', 'Glen, D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-08-09', 'ROOM 3', 'Gynecology', 'Martin, R' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-08-11', 'ROOM 2', 'Cardiology', 'Glen, D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-08-07', 'ROOM 2', 'Vascular', 'Joseph, L' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-08-07', 'ROOM 1', 'Anesthesiology', null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-08-11', 'ROOM 4', 'Cardiology', null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-08-07', 'ROOM 1', 'Orthopedics', null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-08-07', 'ROOM 2', 'Head and Neck', null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-08-09', 'ROOM 3', 'Gynecology', null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-08-08', 'ROOM 1', 'Anesthesiology', null FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| SURGERY_DATE | ROOM_NM | SERVICE_NM | SURGEON_NM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-07 00:00:00 | ROOM 1 | Anesthesiology | *null* |
| 2022-08-07 00:00:00 | ROOM 1 | Orthopedics | Johnson, B |
| 2022-08-07 00:00:00 | ROOM 1 | Orthopedics | Johnson, B |
| 2022-08-07 00:00:00 | ROOM 2 | Head and Neck | *null* |
| 2022-08-07 00:00:00 | ROOM 2 | Vascular | Joseph, L |
| 2022-08-08 00:00:00 | ROOM 1 | Anesthesiology | *null* |
| 2022-08-09 00:00:00 | ROOM 3 | Gynecology | Martin, R |
| 2022-08-09 00:00:00 | ROOM 3 | Gynecology | Martin, R |
| 2022-08-11 00:00:00 | ROOM 2 | Cardiology | Glen, D |
| 2022-08-11 00:00:00 | ROOM 4 | Cardiology | Glen, D |
| 2022-08-11 00:00:00 | ROOM 4 | Cardiology | Glen, D |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GJsEOSf9)

Answer (score 0):

You said that there are other columns in that table, but their values are *distinct*. If there's some unique row identifier (such as *popular* `ID`, which is what I added to my sample data), one option is to use analytic functions. Something like this:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with surgery (id, surgery_date, room_nm, service_nm, surgeon_nm) as
  2    (select 1, date '2022-08-07', 'room 1', 'orthopedics'  , 'johnson' from dual union all
  3     select 2, date '2022-08-11', 'room 4', 'cardiology'   , 'glen'    from dual union all
  4     select 3, date '2022-08-09', 'room 3', 'gynecology'   , 'martin'  from dual union all
  5     select 4, date '2022-08-07', 'room 1', 'anestesiology', null      from dual union all
  6     --
  7     select 5, date '2022-08-07', 'room 1', 'orthopedics'  , null      from dual union all
  8     select 6, date '2022-08-11', 'room 4', 'cardiology'   , null      from dual union all
  9     select 7, date '2022-08-09', 'room 3', 'gynecology'   , null      from dual
 10    )
```

Query:

```
 11  select surgery_date, room_nm, service_nm,
 12    nvl(surgeon_nm,
 13        lag (surgeon_nm) ignore nulls over (partition by surgery_date, room_nm, service_nm
 14                                            order by id)) surgeon_nm
 15  from surgery
 16  order by id;

SURGERY_DA ROOM_N SERVICE_NM    SURGEON
---------- ------ ------------- -------
2022-08-07 room 1 orthopedics   johnson
2022-08-11 room 4 cardiology    glen
2022-08-09 room 3 gynecology    martin
2022-08-07 room 1 anestesiology
2022-08-07 room 1 orthopedics   johnson
2022-08-11 room 4 cardiology    glen
2022-08-09 room 3 gynecology    martin

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```